# Looping through files in R

Tags: r, loops, statistics

I am using R to calculate the mean values of a column in a file like so:

```
R
file1 = read.table("x01")
mean(file1$V4)
```

However I have no experience building loops involving R, only with bash.
How would I convert this into a loop that did this for every file in a folder and saved the output into one file with the file name and mean value as the 2 columns for each row?
eg:

```
x01(or file1 if that is simpler) 23.4
x02 25.4
x03 10.4
```

etc

(Don't mind if the solution is bash and R or exclusively R)
Many thanks for your help!

Current error from one of the solutions using bash and R:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(read.table("PercentWindowConservedRanked_Lowest_cleanfor1000genomes_1000regions_x013",  : 
  undefined columns selected
Calls: mean -> [ -> [.data.frame
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution is also similar to @jmsinger but you can specify the path to your files in the code itself and then calculate the mean like this :

```
filename <- system("ls /dir/",intern=TRUE)

for(i in 1:length(filename)){

file <- read.table(filename[i],header=TRUE) ## if you have headers in your files ##
mean <- mean(file$V4)

write.table(mean,file=paste("/dir",paste("mean",filename[i],sep="."),sep="/")) 
##if you wish to write the means of all the files in seperate files rather than one.
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: looks good but throws error: syntax error near unexpected token `(' from first line

Comment: I think by first line u meant : filename <- system("ls /dir/",intern=TRUE).I tried and its working fine.

Comment: How would I modify your write table command so that all the means are written to the same file?

Comment: You can use the following command : write.table(mean,file="file.txt",append=TRUE)

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to what @jmsigner has done, but with minor changes. For instance, writing to a file is done at the end. The code has not been tested.

```
out <- lapply(list.files(), FUN = function(x) {
    m <- mean(read.table(x, header = TRUE)$V4)
    return(m)
  })
result <- do.call("cbind", out) #merge a list column-wise
# before writing, you can make column names pretty with colnames()
# e.g. colnames(result) <- c("x01", "x02")
write.table(result, file = "means.txt")
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to split the file reading and the calculation of means into two steps.  If the asker wants to calculate other statistics, they need the datasets, which at the moment are being discarded.

Comment: @RichieCotton I wanted to give a general idea of how to use lapply. Of course, one could, or should, tweak the function according to his or her needs.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the columns are always named the same, you could do the following in R:

```
out.file <- 'means.txt'
for (i in list.files()) {
    tmp.file <- read.table(i, header=TRUE)  # Not sure if you have headers or not
    tmp.mean <- mean(tmp.file1$V4)
    write(paste0(i, "," tmp.mean), out.file, append=TRUE)
}
```

Or the same thing with more bash:

```
for i in $(ls *)
do
  mean=$(Rscript -e "mean(read.table('$i', header=T)[, 'V4'])")
  echo $i,$mean >> means.txt
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense to me, although it throws up Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: I believe i missed a `)` it should be fixed now.

Comment: hmm still throws error. The more bash heavy script runs by execution is halted as undefined columns selected. Ive put the full error in my question

Comment: You must specify your column. Since you did not provide an example dataset, I used `V4` from your sample code. Replace `[, 'V4']` either with the number of the desired column (without quotes) or the name of this column.

Comment: currently when specifying $V4 get:^XWarning message:
mean(<data.frame>) is deprecated.
 Use colMeans() or sapply(*, mean) instead. Thanks for the help so far ill play around with it

Comment: ok, if you cant get it to work, consider providing an example dataset

Comment: The syntax arount the `write(paste0` looks wrong, should probably be `write(paste0(i, ",", tmp.mean), out.file, append=TRUE)`, i.e. one more comma and parenthesis closed earlier.